# Getting Pagedown to preview markdown and mathjax at the same time?

Tags: jquery, django, markdown, mathjax, pagedown

First i got a js script to update a preview div from Pagedown textarea/Pagedown widget from Django-pagedown, with the code below:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ["\\(", "\\)"]] }
});

var timeout;
$(function () {
  function makePreview() {
    input = $('#id_content').val().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    $('#id_content_wmd_preview').html(input);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "preview"]);
  }
  $('body').keyup(function () {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(makePreview, 400);
  });
  $('body').bind('updated', function () { makePreview() });
});
```

But the problem is that when this script updates the preview div, it also updates and removes the markdown? If i constantly type then the markdown shows correctly, but not mathjax. If I stop typing the markdown don't show, but mathjax shows correctly?

I know the answer is here https://gist.github.com/gdalgas/a652bce3a173ddc59f66 but i don't know how to do it. Looks like i have to remove and store the math, and then put it back in later.

Comment: How did you manage to incorporate the JS script and django-pagedown together?